# Sendy ajax subscribe call with json

Tags: ajax

I am trying to get user to subscribe on the website using sendy subscription form (via ajax).

The problem is it shows no error and console.log stuck with "signing in...".

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#emailListSignupForm").submit(function(e) {

        console.log('submitting');
        e.preventDefault();

        var thisis = jQuery( this );

        thisis.find('input').attr("disabled", "disabled");

        jQuery("#status").text("Signing You in...");


        var testList = "ID GOES HERE";
        var name = thisis.find('input[name="name"]').val();
        var email = thisis.find('input[name="email"]').val();
        var sendyUrl = "http://PATH GOES HERE/subscribe";
        var dataObject = {name: name,email: email,list: testList};


        window.message = function(text, color) {
            jQuery("#status").css("color", color).text(text);
        }

        jQuery("#status").text("Sending details....");


        jQuery.ajax({

            url: sendyUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: dataObject,
            success: function( response ) { 
            console.log( response );                
                if ( response ) {
                    thisis.find('input').removeAttr("disabled");
                    if (response == "Some fields are missing.") {
                      jQuery("#status").text("Please fill in your name and email.");
                    } else if (response == "Invalid email address.") {
                      jQuery("#status").text("Uhoh - that doesn't look like an email address. Could you please enter your email again?"); 
                    } else if (response == "Invalid list ID.") {
                        jQuery("#status").text("Oops - something went wrong (I tried to sign you up for an email list that doesn't exist). To get added, send me an email at christian@gen.co instead!"); 
                    } else if (response == "Already subscribed.") {
                        jQuery("#status").text("You're already subscribed!"); 
                    } else {
                      jQuery("#status").text("You're subscribed!");
                      jQuery("#status").css("color", "green");
                      thisis.find('input, button').hide();
                    }
                  } else {
                    alert("Sorry, unable to subscribe. Please try again later!");
                    jQuery("#status").text("Oops - something went wrong (my email list server just had an error). To get added, send me an email at christian@gen.co instead!");
                  }
            }

        });

    });


});
```

Comment: It seems that you are not using [WP Ajax API](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) and that your question is not related with WordPress. One thing I see wrong in your code is that you are saying to jQuery that `response` is in JSONP format but you are checking the `response` as string. I think you would get better answers in StackOverflow.

Comment: You have no error handler for your AJAX call. There could be an issue with the XmlHttpRequest that is not getting properly logged. You might be missing a status code that is not being handled because you only have the success handler, which is HTTP status code 200. You might have a 500 error, or some other error that would only get handled in an error handler.

Comment: Looking back at your question, it seems that it is hitting the success handler, however, the code is not stepping inside the first if statement. That could mean that the response is coming back as null or some other "falsey" value. It's important to probably debug the error on the server to see what is being returned to the client.